# update Angular project with all dependencys

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli, capacitor

Currently I am working with an angular project which has dependencies of the following versions:

```
Angular: 12
Node: 14.21.2
capacitor/andorid: 4.5.0
capacitor/app: 1.0.6
...
Angular CLI (ng version): Node.js version v14.21.3 detected. The Angular CLI requires a minimum of v16.13 -> this message occures because I only have updated node
```

Now I want update the project to Angular 16 and all dependency (especially capacitor, Node, and Angular CLI) therefore that all fits together.
My question now would be how to do this because I don't know e.g. which capacitor version fits to the Angular 16 version and so on.
Is there any command which updates die package.json file therefore, that all versions fit together or how is the way to update all dependency that in the end all works fine again?

This is my package.json file:

```
 {
 "name": "my-app",
 "version": "0.0.1",
 "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~12.1.1",
    "@capacitor/android": "4.5.0",
    "@capacitor/app": "1.0.6",
    "@capacitor/haptics": "1.1.3",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "1.1.3",
    "@capacitor/push-notifications": "^5.0.6",
    "@capacitor/splash-screen": "^4.1.4",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "1.0.6",
    "@capgo/capacitor-updater": "^4.17.46",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.5.2",
    "@ionic/storage-angular": "^3.0.6",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "ionic-color-picker": "^1.0.3",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.7",
    "tslib": "^2.2.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "~12.0.1",
    "@capacitor/cli": "^4.5.0",
    "@capacitor/core": "^4.5.0",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.16.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.16.1",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "30.7.6",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "typescript": "~4.2.4"
  },
  "description": "myApp"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular provides great docs for upgrading Angular here: https://update.angular.io/ - I suggest you read the docs but I'll provide a summary with some tips.

First you'll need to upgrade to Node 18 or 20. v14 is already EOL and 16 will be in September, 2023.

For Angular packages you can run `ng update @angular/cli@X` where X is the version you want to upgrade to, and this upgrades all your angular packages. Often though, if you have third party libraries you will need to use the force flag because incompatible peer dependencies will cause it to fail:

```
ng update @angular/cli@16 --force
```

And then subsequently update your peer dependencies. The schematic should take care of most breaking changes but be sure to read through the checklist and fix anything the schematic missed.

For Capacitor and Capacitor plugins, they are completely unrelated to Angular, so you can upgrade them separately. I suggest you use the CLI migration tool, that you run with `npx cap migrate`. This also often fails though, so you'll want to read the terminal output and the [docs](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/updating/5-0) to make sure you get everything.